# How to send FormData including File to postMessage of Web Worker?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an uploading feature in React, I want to do it in multi-threading. I have a `apiWorker.ts` file

```
const workercode = () => {
    self.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log("Message received from main script");
        const workerResult = "Received from main: " + e.data;
        console.log("okkkk", "Posting message back to main script");
        self.postMessage(workerResult);
    };
};

let code = workercode.toString();
code = code.substring(code.indexOf("{") + 1, code.lastIndexOf("}"));

const blob = new Blob([code], { type: "application/javascript" });
const WorkerScript = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
export default WorkerScript;
```

Then in my main Component, I import it like this

```
import WorkerScript from "src/worker/apiWorker";
const CreateReport = () => {
const worker = new Worker(WorkerScript);
const formData = new FormData();
fileList.filter((file) => !isLargerThan10Mb(file as RcFile)).forEach((file) => { formData.append("files", file.originFileObj as Blob);
});
formData.append("channel", "upload_report");
formData.append("import_mode", `${isDeletePrev}`);
const object = {};

//I tried this but it's not working
formData.forEach((value, key) => {
object[key] = value;
});
const json = JSON.stringify(object);
const msg = { form_data: json };
worker.postMessage(msg);

...
}
```

I've read previous questions but none of them include File in FormData. Is there any way to Structured Clone Algorithm FormData to send it to postMessage? Simple like this:

```
 worker.postMessage('hi');
```

and the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkZcR.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.